# how to add specific comment to post in django post

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

I have posts that, user can add comments to, but i unable to add those comments to that specific posts, here is the code that I'm following:-
the code is working fine with models and the only issue is when comment added, its added to only one post, rather than specific comment to specific post
HTML Code

```
 <div class="quote-comment-box">
                <form method="POST" class="com">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input placeholder="Your thought"  type="text" name="quote-comment" class="comment-input" id="{{ quote.id }}" title="{{ quote.user.id }}" data="{{ request.user }}">
                    <button type="submit" href="{% url 'micro__blog:quote_comment' %}" class="comment-button">POST</button>
                </form>

                <div class="content" id="content">
                </div>
            </div>
```

js code

```
 $('.comment-button').click(function (params) {
    csrftoken()
    var index = $('.comment-button').index(this)
    var comment = $( ".comment-input" ).eq(index).val()
    var id = $( ".content" ).eq(index).attr('id')
    params.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        url:$(this).attr("href"),
        data:{
            'blog_id' : $( '.comment-input' ).eq(index).attr('id'),
            'blog_user' : $( '.comment-input' ).eq(index).attr('title'),
            'comment' : $( ".comment-input" ).eq(index).val(),
        },
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (res, status) {
           
            if (res['status'] == 'ok') {
                $('.comment-input').eq(index).val('');
                var content = $('.content').eq(index)
                console.log(index, content)
                    const div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.className = "comment-added"
                    div.innerHTML = `
                    <span class="user">` + $( ".comment-input" ).eq(index).attr('data') + `</span>
                    <span class="text">` +  comment + `</span>`;
                    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
                console.log(res.status)
              } else {
              console.log(res.status)
              }
        },
        error: function (res) {
            console.log(res.status);                                                                                                                          
        }
    })
```

Here is view code

```
def quote_comment(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    blog_id = request.POST.get('blog_id')
    blog_user = request.POST.get('blog_user')
    comment = request.POST.get('comment')
    current_user = User.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
    if blog_id and blog_user and comment and current_user:
        blog_id = Quote.objects.get(id = blog_id)
        blog_user = User.objects.get(id=blog_user)
        try:
            QuoteComment.objects.get_or_create(user=current_user,blog_id=blog_id,blog_user_id=blog_user,comment=comment)
            return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'error'})
return JsonResponse({'status':'error'})
```

and url

```
    path('quote_comment/', views.quote_comment, name="quote_comment"),
```

A view that renders this template

```
def index(request):
   quotes= Quote.objects.all()
return render(request=request, template_name="dashboard.html",context={'quotes':quotes})
```

to render on quotes im suing for loop like this
{% for quote in quotes %}

{% endfor %}

Comment: We can't say anything without seeing the rest of the code (esp. your view).

Comment: updated with view and url @Selcuk

Comment: Also the view that renders that HTML template please.

Comment: hey, @Selcuk updated that view also

Comment: You pass a `posts` context variable to the template, where do you use that? Can you please post all the relevant information?

Comment: My bad, now its has all relevant info.